# Are stack buffer overflows even possible in this instance?

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode, aslr, dep

Let's say there is a C program that simply takes a string `argv[1]` and uses `sprintf` to copy it in a finite buffer.  Classic stack buffer overflow.  Let's even say the program is more complicated, allowing for techniques like ROP.

But then it's compiled with a stack canary/security cookie, and run on an OS using ASLR and DEP.

Does not the chance to then execute arbitrary shellcode approach 0?

Comment: It gets harder, but not impossible [This question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45593/on-hawkes-technique-to-bypass-canaries) discusses getting past a canary. ROP, which you mention is a way to get past DEP. ASLR is another difficulty, but can be brute-forced on a 32-bit system, and there are other weaknesses.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

DEP blocks you from just doing a jump to `esp` and executing code there. ASLR is your major important thing to bypass here.

There are a number of ways that you might be able to do this:

- Modules loaded into the process which don't have ASLR enabled. There are a bunch of ways this might happen:

  - DLLs that are a part of your application which were compiled without the ASLR flag.
  - Injected as part of the AppInit DLLs.
  - Injected by 3rd party applications, e.g. anti-virus or something like xfire / Fraps.
  - Shell handlers loaded alongside `shdoclc.dll` when you use the standard file dialogs.
- Fixed-address allocations (e.g. `VirtualAlloc` with the `lpAddress` parameter set)
- Secondary vulnerabilities that allow for memory disclosure or pointer disclosure may be useful in building up an idea of where things are in memory.
- Corrupting the stack in some way that triggers a secondary issue, e.g. heap corruption. This could then open up other exploitation avenues, using tricks such as heap spraying, heap feng-shui, JIT spraying, etc.